# How to know which version of Neutron is included in Openstack 3.18 Stein release?

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I have a code snippet which will not work for Kilo version. I know the Openstack version, now I'm willing to know step/s to fetch the neutron version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.18 is the version of the openstack command line client, not the version of OpenStack.

There are [several possible Neutron versions](https://docs.openstack.org/releasenotes/neutron/stein.html) in Stein, all starting with 14. To obtain the precise version, either check the Python code or run `neutron-db-manage version --verbose` on a controller (see [the documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/latest/contributor/alembic_migrations.html) for information about this command).

There is no API that gives you the version of the deployed software. You obtain the *API version* by sending an HTTP GET to the bare Neutron endpoint, e.g. `curl http://example.com:9696`.

While I can't promise anything (it may be hard to find a Kilo installation for checking), feel free to publish your code here, stating what exactly works and doesn't work in which version.

Comment: I wanted to know the steps to check neutron version. Your comments helped in that.